# Find usages of referenced assembly in a C# project in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am currently digging through a fairly big project and trying to seperate out parts into own projects.

One assembly is giving me a headache since referencing it in the seperated project throws an error regarding circular dependency.

My question is now how to find all usages of a specific assembly reference in a project?

Comment: Easiest way would be to remove the assembly from the references and attempt to build the project. All the errors given will show you where it is attempting to be used.

Comment: Uh, yes - that worked quite well haha. Sometimes we're just thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be to remove the assembly from the references and attempt to build the project. All the errors given will show you where it is attempting to be used.

Comment: I also use this method but I'd prefer not to do that each time I need to quick check.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this PowerShell snippet in your source code directory, it will produce a textual description of all your project dependencies. Then search it for the name of your project to find incoming and outgoing dependencies.

```
$projectFiles = Get-ChildItem .\*\*.csproj
$ns = @{ defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }

$projectFiles | ForEach-Object {
    $projectFile = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    $projectName = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
    $projectXml = [xml](Get-Content $projectFile)

    $projectReferences = $projectXml | Select-Xml '//defaultNamespace:ProjectReference/defaultNamespace:Name' -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"

    $projectReferences | ForEach-Object {
        "[" + $projectName + "] -> [" + $_ + "]"
    }
}
```

Added bonus; you can copy the output into [yuml.me](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw) and it will build you a diagram of your solution dependencies.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. I needed the exact line in the codebase where something of the assembly has been used.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll leave it as an answer because someone else might find it useful if they happen upon this question later.

Comment: It's not related to question because we already know an assembly is referenced, but very useful. I think you better create a Wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) for that, or ask a question and answer yourself.

Comment: Good script. I just had to add recursivity : "Get-ChildItem -recurse .\\*\\*.csproj"